# .htaccess remove subdirectory name from all URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I was digging the net and haven't found any proper solution for this issue. Basically, I want to remove subdirectory (**subdirname**) name from all URLs, e.g.:

```
http://test.com/subdirname/
http://test.com/subdirname/content/
http://test.com/subdirname/content/newpage
```

The website is based on Wordpress and located in **/subdirname**. I've got two .htaccess files, one in root directory:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/var|/static)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/var|/static)

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/subdirname/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirname/$1 [L]
```

and second in /subdirname/ directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirname/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirname/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

---

If anyone has some tips how to solve it, please advice.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just reconfigure wordpress's site URL at `/` but leave it installed in `/subdirname/`?

Comment: Did you mean changing it in WP admin panel Settings -> General ?

Comment: Yeah. You can have it so the wordpress site itself is at `/` but it is installed in a different directory.

Comment: This won't solve the problem. It will just make it worst by blocking access to wp-admin page. I've tried that already.

Comment: It seems like using mod_rewrite to remove `subdirname` will block access to wp-admin. On my wordpress setup in the General Settings panel, `WordPress Address (URL)` = `http://mydomain.com/subdir`, `Site Address (URL)` = `http://mydomain.com/` and everything works fine. Including all wp-admin stuff, and I didn't need to modify anything in htaccess.

Comment: @Jon Lin

I'm afraid of messing in Wordpress settings site URL as this previously caused me serious headache and extra work to fix. As I mentioned, this did not work for my site. Could you help me with htaccess modification?

Comment: If wordpress isn't going to do this for you, I have no idea what rules is going to work since wordpress is going to *expect* a /subdirname/ in the URI and you want to *remove it*.

Comment: That's why I want to use .htaccess file in root directory to solve this issue and this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to set up [WordPress to display at your root domain but be installed in the subdirectory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). Just change ONLY the site URL under the Settings-> General screen. Leave the subdirectory in the WordPress URL box. Then you would login at http://yoursite.com/subdirectory/wp-admin, but folks visit your site at http://yoursite.com.

Comment: I used the instructions in the "Using a pre-existing subdirectory install" section of the page rentageekmom mentioned (i.e. https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and all went smoothly. WordPress is installed in a sub-directory and can be accessed with or without specifying the sub-directory as part of the URL.